# Pivot group by data

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to transpose and group data to look like this:

[image: transposed and grouped data]

Current group by data:

```
              MTD-Total Revenue  YTD-Total Revenue  MTD-Room Revenue  YTD-Room Revenue  MTD-Room Nights  YTD-Room Nights  MTD-ADR  YTD-ADR  MTD-OCC%  YTD-OCC%
Market Group
Aff                         0.0                0.0        2026136.99       21546922.96            857.0           8650.0  2457.02  2551.87      4.99      4.16
Air                         0.0                0.0        2809312.53       32534587.15            925.0           9684.0  2392.08  3016.00      2.69      2.33
BAR                         0.0                0.0         470866.23        8341596.95            131.0           2481.0  3189.75  3133.08      0.76      1.19
Cas                         0.0                0.0        4801710.10       55466024.12           1652.0          18566.0  2365.23  2585.25      1.92      1.79
Com                         0.0                0.0        3873151.63       43857524.55           1088.0          11980.0  2449.43  2632.57      6.34      5.76
Cor                         0.0                0.0        7104841.79       88326080.23           2314.0          26836.0  1552.74  2919.07      4.14      3.97
Pro                         0.0                0.0         335358.36        1907348.23             97.0            562.0  3457.30  3393.86      2.26      1.08
Soc                         0.0                0.0          12706.96          82957.59              4.0             25.0  1588.37  3315.74      0.04      0.02
TA                          0.0                0.0        1016565.12       15563472.77            416.0           6797.0  2412.55  2229.46      4.84      6.54
Wal                         0.0                0.0         277267.66        3786378.41             68.0            812.0  4077.47  4663.03      1.58      1.56
```

[image: Group by data]

Codes ran:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,5))
df.reset_index().pivot('Market Group', 'MTD-Total Revenue', 'YTD-Total Revenue')
```

How data looks if it were to be transposed: `df.T`:

[image: df.T]

Comment: Do you have the original data in csv form so I can play around with it, I can't copy and paste the current group by data into something I can manipulate.

Comment: @RichardKYu, Not sure how to attach a file here, but the data is very similar to the current group by data on top. Just copy and delimiter it by space in excel (sorry about that). Trying to use the code `pd.DataFrame(df6.values.reshape(-1,1))` which does help but drops the header and index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this would be :

```
df= pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Market Group'], value_vars=['MTD-Total Revenue','YTD-Total Revenue','MTD-Room Revenue','YTD-Room Revenue','MTD-Room Nights','YTD-Room Nights','MTD-ADR','YTD-ADR','MTD-OCC%','YTD-OCC%'])
```

This keeps the headers unlike using unstack or stack .